# MATLAB GUI error Reference to non-existent field '---'

Tags: matlab, user-interface, char, integer

I have two edittext boxes. I want to give an error message as soon as user clicks another place rather than these edittext boxes. I receive message

> Reference to non-existent field 'eth_xegim'.

In fact, I have several edittext boxes before these two. When I print `S`, I can see the fieldnames are printed up to `xegim` but not `xegim`

```
S.fh = figure('Visible','on','numbertitle','off','Name','GUI',...
    'units','pixels','Position',[50 50 1500 750]);
% Panel start
S.ph_arazi = uipanel('Parent',S.fh,'Title','Arazi','TitlePosition','centertop',...
    'units','pixels','Position',[1180 364 300 244]);

S.sth_xegim = uicontrol(S.ph_arazi,'Style','text','String','x Eksenine gore egim [%]','HorizontalAlignment','left','Position',[10 68 130 18]);
% xegim edittext
S.eth_xegim = uicontrol(S.ph_arazi,'Style','edit','String','0',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right','BackgroundColor','w',...
    'Position',[250 68 40 18],'callback',{@errmsg,S});

S.sth_yegim = uicontrol(S.ph_arazi,'Style','text',...
    'String','y Eksenine gore egim [%]','HorizontalAlignment','left',...
    'Position',[10 40 130 18]);
% xegim edittext
S.eth_yegim = uicontrol(S.ph_arazi,'Style','edit',...
    'String','0','HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'BackgroundColor','w','Position',[250 40 40 18],...
    'callback',{@errmsg,S});
% error message
function [] = errmsg(varargin)
S = varargin{3} 

xegim = get(S.eth_xegim,'String');
xegim = xegim(ismember(xegim,'.:0123456789'));
yegim = get(S.eth_yegim,'String');
yegim = yegim(ismember(yegim,'.:0123456789'));
if isempty(xegim) || isempty(yegim)
    if length(S.fh)==1
        S.fh(2) = figure('numbertitle','off','Name','Error',...
            'menubar','none','units','pixels',...
            'Position',[700 400 200 100]);

        S.sth_error = uicontrol(S.fh(2),'Style','text',...
            'String','Girdiler sayi olmali!','Min',0,'Max',2,...
            'BackgroundColor','r','Position',[10 10 180 80]);
        ag = findobj; 
        nf = max(ag(find(ag==fix(ag))));
        if nf == 2
        close(S.fh(2))
        end
        S.fh(2) = [];
    end
    return;
end
```

Comment: Ok, except that the title is completely unrelated to the text, I some really simple debugging of this script using the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html?refresh=true). The result was that I found a typo causing your crash. I give this as a comment since a) The title is not related to question 2) The error message does not appear where you say it does 3) There are no question in the post. This means that I have no idea what to answer, so i beg your pardon for the formatting. `S =  fh: [1x1 Figure],  ph_arazi: [1x1 Panel],  sth_xegim: [1x1 UIControl]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time you add `S` to the callback as an additional input argument `S` does not contain the fields `eth_xegim` and `eth_yegim` as they have not been added to the structure. Define the callbacks after fields have been added:

```
S.eth_xegim = uicontrol(S.ph_arazi,'Style','edit','String','0',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right','BackgroundColor','w',...
    'Position',[250 68 40 18]);

S.eth_yegim = uicontrol(S.ph_arazi,'Style','edit',...
    'String','0','HorizontalAlignment','right',...
    'BackgroundColor','w','Position',[250 40 40 18]);


S.eth_xegim.Callback = {@errmsg,S};
S.eth_yegim.Callback = {@errmsg,S};
```